# Ошибки при объявлении и использовании строки

Tags: c, строки

```
char outputString[400];
if (lengthOutput == 0) 
{
    outputString = "no solution";
    printf("no solution");
}
```

Из этих шести строк мне VS2017 выдаёт две ошибки:

1. `C3863` - тип `char [400]` является неназначаемым (относится к строке с объявлением)
2. `E0137` - выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением (относится к строке с присваиванием)

Что это значит вообще и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так все получится:

```
strcpy(outputString,"no solution");
```

Ну, разве что скажет, что лучше использовать безопасную функцию `strcpy_s`, что в данном случае тоже вполне допустимо даже без исправлений:

```
strcpy_s(outputString,"no solution");
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек!